# Angular Reactive forms Select default object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using reactive forms and I have a select box that comes from an array of objects. I tried to set the default value but it just doesn't set.

My form:

```
<form [formGroup]="markerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(markerForm)" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="markerType">{{ 'MARKER.LABEL_TYPE' | translate }}</label>
        <select  class="form-control" formControlName="markerType"   >
           <option id="markerType" [value]="markerType.id" *ngFor="let markerType of markerTypes">{{markerType.desc}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
</form>
```

Set default value:

```
const test= [{id:1, desc: 'Restaurants'}, {id:2, desc : 'Fire stations'}];
this.markerTypes= test;
console.log(this.markerTypes[1].desc);
this.markerForm.controls['markerType'].setValue( this.markerTypes[1], {onlySelf: true});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem happened because you are using `markerType.id` as a value but sending the whole object `this.markerTypes[1]` as default. You should pass `this.markerTypes[1].id` in this case.

If you want to use objects as values you should use `ngValue` directive on option tag:

```
<option id="markerType" [ngValue]="markerType" *ngFor="let markerType of markerTypes">{{markerType.desc}}</option>
```

This is because [unlike the value binding, ngValue supports binding to objects](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption)

See the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1qdpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer is correct and work, but if i want to pass this.makerTypes[1] it just dont work, check this link please https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-znqfzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Oh, I got it. Than you should use ngValue instead of value. See, I've updated my answer and stackblitz example

Answer (score 4):

You're setting your default value as an Object:

```
this.markerForm.controls['markerType'].setValue( this.markerTypes[1], {onlySelf: true});
```

And you're saying that your value is an id:

```
 <option id="markerType" [value]="markerType.id" *ngFor="let markerType of markerTypes">{{markerType.desc}}</option>
```

You have multiple choices here, it depends how you want your form value to be.

**Using Id:**

```
this.markerForm.controls['markerType'].setValue( this.markerTypes[1].id, {onlySelf: true});

<option id="markerType" [value]="markerType.id" *ngFor="let markerType of markerTypes">{{markerType.desc}}</option>
```

**Using Desc:**

```
this.markerForm.controls['markerType'].setValue( this.markerTypes[1].desc, {onlySelf: true});

<option id="markerType" [value]="markerType.desc" *ngFor="let markerType of markerTypes">{{markerType.desc}}</option>
```

**Using Object:**

In this case you have to use [ngValue], [value] is used only for type string variables.

```
this.markerForm.controls['markerType'].setValue( this.markerTypes[1], {onlySelf: true});

<option id="markerType" [value]="markerType" *ngFor="let markerType of markerTypes">{{markerType.desc}}</option>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bbabmf)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

Try this

check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqhchz?embed=1

**Component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="markerForm">
   <select id="country" formControlName="markerType">
       <option *ngFor="let c of markerTypes" [ngValue]="c.id">{{ c.desc }} 
      </option>
   </select>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class Component {

   markerTypes = [{id:1,desc:'abc'}, {id: 2,desc:'xyz'}];
   default= 1;

   markerForm: FormGroup;

   constructor() {
       this.markerForm= new FormGroup({
           markerType: new FormControl(null)
       });
     this.markerForm.controls['markerType'].setValue(this.default, {onlySelf: true});
    }
}
```

Hope this will help